# Generate unique string within specific length range

Tags: java, arrays, string, random, generator

I faced some difficulties to figure out how to generate unique string within  [1;200) range length. The code I've come up with attached below:

```
public static String generateRandString() {

    String STRING_TOKENS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    while(stringBuilder.length() <= 200) {
        int index = (int) random.nextFloat() * STRING_TOKENS.length();
        stringBuilder.append(STRING_TOKENS.charAt(index));
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**The Problem:**

Requesting 20 generated strings returns every time "AAAAAAAA" string probably of 200 symbols length

Expected output:

```
A7898as7sd6as5da
as87asd67
768asjhg435GhA900324
2g2j3h4gjhgAKL*78a9dd879234
3B234
1
```

Some limitations:

1. No additional libraries (Google Guava or Apache Common)
2. JDK 1.6 only

Many thanks to your contribution!

Comment: Just something to be aware of, but note that your approach cannot guarantee a unique String. It is *very* unlikely given that the length of the String is 200, but possible that you will get a close-enough sequence of randomly generated values from `random.nextFloat()` that you will be grabbing the same characters from your `STRING_TOKENS`.

Comment: Hint: `(int) random.nextFloat() * STRING_TOKENS.length()` is the same as `((int) random.nextFloat()) * STRING_TOKENS.length()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `int index = random.nextInt(STRING_TOKENS.length());`

**In Java 1.7 or later**, the standard way to  to generate a random int value, but in a specific range is as follows:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

// nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
// so add 1 to make it inclusive
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-)

**Before Java 1.7**

```
 int randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Comment: This actually works! But how do i receive string of a length withing range [1;200) ? it would be great if Random could generate with min, max...

Comment: @Reborn Since you can generate with a Max value you can simply generate from a minimum to a maximum by basic math and doing `int rnd = MIN + random.nextInt(MAX-MIN)` , so if you wanted to generate numbers between 100-200 you cound just do `100+random.nextInt(100)`

Comment: @MikeAdamenko it could be easier to write code for 1.7, but restrictions...

Answer (score 4):

Try this !!!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(randomString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 200)));


static String randomString(int len) {
    String AB = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you want to generate unique string. You can use **java.util.UUID**

```
import java.util.UUID;
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
int index = (int) random.nextFloat() * STRING_TOKENS.length();
```

Here, you cast `random.nextFloat()` to `int` *before* the multiplication, thus always ending up with `0 * something`. Add some parentheses:

```
int index = (int) (random.nextFloat() * STRING_TOKENS.length());
```

Or better, use `nextInt` instead:

```
int index = random.nextInt(STRING_TOKENS.length());
```

---

If you also want to randomize the length of the string, roll another number for use in the condition in the `while` loop:

```
int max = random.nextInt(200);
while(stringBuilder.length() <= max) {
```

Answer (score 2):

In your line `(int) random.nextFloat() * STRING_TOKENS.length()` your int cast will be applied only to `random.nextFloat()` and since this value is between 0.0 and 1.0 the result of that cast will almost allways be 0 and your whole value will be 0 as well (As 0 * X is 0).

Use parenthesis: `(int) (random.nextFloat() * STRING_TOKENS.length())` to apply the cast to the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

Others have talked about making random strings.  For guaranteed uniqueness you could use the string's hash code.  If two strings have different hash codes then they are guaranteed not to be the same.  As each string is generated, put its hash code into a set/array/whatever.  If the hash code is already there (unlikely but possible) then reject that particular string and generate an alternative.

I'm not sure what is available in Java 1.6, so I won't write any actual code, but the idea is not difficult to implement.

Comment: Good idea. I'll give it a shot.